# Getting false Answer from path.exists()

Tags: python, pathlib

I am new to Python and recently while working with directories, I found a library called `pathlib`
I created a new Directory under the same project called `ecommerce` , in which I made a python file as-

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("Basics")
print(path.exists())
```

Output -

```
False
```

I have another directory named `Basics` in the same project, I want to check whether it exists or not using `exists()` method. It is returning `False` but when I run the same code on my console, it gives the answer as `True`. Kindly help

Comment: It is looking for `Basics` in the _current directory_, not anywhere on the entire computer.

Comment: I am following a course in which the instructor makes a file in one of the directories and searches for another directory from within that directory [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uQrJ0TkZlc) 03:44:37 Working with Directories

Comment: Please check it once it's only a minute long, you can find the exact time in table of contents